# How to integrate razorpay payment gateway in react native expo project

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway

I have created the project in **react native expo-cli** and at the very end situation of a project I stuck to implements **razor pay payment gateway as expo-cli** does not support payment gateway

if anyone can help me

Answer (score 3):

Step - 1 : Detach the project using expo Kit.

Step - 2 : Follow the steps for [razorPay](https://github.com/razorpay/react-native-razorpay)

Step - 3 : You need not to design any UI for the payment. Razorpay gives that by default

NOTE - RazorPay has to be linked to native modules so you need to detach the project with or without using expoKit is the only way out.

Answer (score 2):

RazorPay doesn't support Expo. so Eject your app from Expo and follow  the instructions.

https://github.com/razorpay/react-native-razorpay

Answer (score 0):

[EAS](https://blog.expo.dev/eas-build-april-preview-update-ebd7dff9dd25) builds officially released in Expo SDK 42 makes it possible to run native modules on expo project without ejecting.

In order to make sure Razorpay wrapper works correctly:

- Create a dev build of your expo app by following the instructions mentioned [here](https://docs.expo.dev/development/build/).
- run your project by running the following command
- For ios

  `expo run:ios`
- For android

  `expo run:android`